# Alternative for @Autowired in Spring, which won't initialize the bean before test class setup

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test, dbunit

I have a Spring Bean class which communicates with the DB, and I'm working on writing a test case for it.

I'm making use of DbUnit which sets up an in-memory database (based on extending a base DbUnit class) using JUnit Annotation **@Before**.

The issue is with the **@Autowired** bean I'm trying to test: it accesses the database in its **@Postconstruct** method, and this happens before DB Setup, note the class itself is annotated with **@Component**.

So, I need a way or annotation to use so that the bean I'm testing gets initialized only after the @Before JUnit method runs.

Comment: That has nothing to do with `@Autowired`... That has to do with the fact that you have a `@PostConstruct` bean.

Comment: Correct, answer is below !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is common problem for spring and there is common solution to solve it.
You need to build so-called "three phase construction".

Generally you want to initialize your bean only after you set all your spring context (with database). So you need to listen when spring will be initialized and then execute your logic.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface PostProxy {
}
```

This class should be defined as a bean within your context.

```
public class PostProxySpringContextListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostProxySpringContextListener.class);

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    ApplicationContext context = event.getApplicationContext();
    String[] beanDefinitionNames = context.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    for (String beanDefinitionName : beanDefinitionNames) {
        String originalClassName = getOriginalClassName(beanDefinitionName, event);
        if (originalClassName != null) {
            invokeAnnotatedMethods(context, beanDefinitionName, originalClassName);
        }
    }
}

private String getOriginalClassName(String name, ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    try {
        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory =
                (ConfigurableListableBeanFactory)event.getApplicationContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        BeanDefinition beanDefinition = factory.getBeanDefinition(name);
        return beanDefinition.getBeanClassName();
    } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException e) {
        LOG.debug("Can't get bean definition for : " + name);
        return null;
    }
}

private void invokeAnnotatedMethods(ApplicationContext context, String beanDefinitionName, String originalClassName) {
    try {
        Class<?> originalClass = Class.forName(originalClassName);
        Method[] methods = originalClass.getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(PostProxy.class)) {
                LOG.info("Executing @PostProxy annotated initialization method: " + method.toString());
                Object bean = context.getBean(beanDefinitionName);
                Method currentMethod = bean.getClass().getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
                currentMethod.invoke(bean);
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        LOG.trace("No class instance for bean " + beanDefinitionName + " with class name " + originalClassName);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        LOG.error("Error finding @PostProxy method for bean " + beanDefinitionName, e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        LOG.error("Error invoking @PostProxy method for bean " + beanDefinitionName, e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        LOG.error("Can't invoke annotated method in bean" + beanDefinitionName + " with class name " + originalClassName
                + ". Please check access modifiers on @PostProxy methods.", e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so if I just add these 2 classes, and define PostProxySpringContextListener as a bean in my spring context, then my classes would get loaded after @Postconstruct ?

Comment: Yes. And you need to annotate your db-dependent initialization method with @PostProxy

Comment: Perfect brotha, it works ! Had to remove @PostConstruct obviously.

Comment: While this solved my problem, I have another issue now which requires my Spring Bean to be initialized **after** JUnit's '@BeforeClass' or '@Before methods'; the reason is my Spring Bean is accessing another bean saved in the Stub/Mocked JSF Session, and so I need to set this value in my test '@Before'. Thanks for any further help.

Comment: I guess you still need to initialize spring context in your test. Just configuraiton of this context should be prior to your test with appropriate mocks.

Comment: I am running the test case using '@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)' and I am also specifying the context XML file locations. The issue is occuring WHEN the Spring context is starting up. On '@PostProxy' the class is accessing JSF-Context file which are usually mocked '@Before', among other static values.

Comment: Are you using xml's to configure spring or annotations?

Comment: XMLs usually, but for my tests I started introducing Annotations, so it is now hybrid. The reason I added Annotations is that JSF 'BackedBeans' (similar to Controllers) were defined in the JSF IoC contrainer only in faces-managed-beans.xml which injects the Spring managed beans based on the property name; this led me to make my BB's '@Component' and the Spring Beans inside it '@Autowired'.

Comment: So with xml's it's simple. you just split your xml into several parts and for test provide xml with your mocks instead of 'production' beans. With annotations im not sure, try to post another question on SO.